# How to use report() function with a specific channel in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

You can define your log channels in `config/logging.php` as I have already done.

Then you can send a log to your new channel like this:

```
Log::channel('my-channel')->error('message');
```

Now, when I want to **catch** an exception without throwing it, I usually use the `report()` helper function like this:

```
try{
   throw new Exception('message');
}catch(Exception $e){
   report($e);
}
```

That is very useful for continuing a script after an exception is thrown, but it always logs the exception to my default logging channel.

I want to use the `report()` function **and** specify that it should be reported to `my-channel`.

I played around with `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` without any luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far I decided to just make a simple class to emulate `report()` instead of trying to use it directly:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Log;
use Throwable;

class Reporter
{
    /**
     * Reports an exception to a specific channel.
     * 
     * @param Throwable $e
     * @param string $channel
     * @param array $context
     */
    public static function report(Throwable $e, $channel = 'daily', $context = [])
    {
        Log::channel($channel)->error(
            $e->getMessage(),
            array_merge(
                Context::getContext(),
                $context,
                ['exception' => $e],
            )
        );
    }
}
```

And you would use it like this:

```
try{
   throw new Exception('message');
}catch(Exception $e){
   Reporter::report($e, 'my-channel');
}
```

You can also pass extra context to the log message as an array.